# How to turn Android text-to-Speech inside GPS LocationListener?

Tags: android, gps, text-to-speech

Is it possible to turn the text to speech feature on inside the LocatioListener class??

I'm trying to make an android application detect how far you have moved. I am able to turn on the GPS, and monitor for location movement. I would like to make it say "You have moved 300meters". It would be very convenient to put it inside the OnLocation method, but it complains when i try to instantiate the texttospeech??

This is what I was trying:

```
public class Location implements LocationListener {
    static TextToSpeech talk;
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
```

//This yells at me on next line, won't let me use 'this' as context?? (Also tried Location.this)

```
        talk = new TextToSpeech(this, new extToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
        public void onInit(int status) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            talk.setLanguage(Locale.UK);
            Location aloc = new Location("aloc");
            Location bloc = new Location("bloc");
            aloc.setLatitude(alat);
            aloc.setLongitude(alon);
            bloc.setLatitude(blat);
            bloc.setLongitude(blon);

            float distance = aloc.distanceTo(bloc);
            talk.speak("You Moved..", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
            }
    });     


}

public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a reference to a `Context` in order to initialise the TTS engine. Hence it will not work with `this` or `Location.this`, since both refer to the running instance of your `Location` class, which obviously is *not* a `Context` (or subclass of it).

That being said, there are multiple options.

1. If you use your `Location` class as anonymous innerclass or non-static innerclass in e.g. an `Activity` (or any other class where you *can* get a reference to a `Context` object), you can use a reference to the outer class to initialise the TTS engine.
2. In stead of trying to initialise the TTS engine directly inside the `Location` class, initialize it somewhere where you *do* have a `Context` reference; e.g. the same place where you request the `LocationManager` (for which you already need a `Context` reference).
3. Create a centralized instance of the TTS engine. You could set it up as singleton, but can also subclass `Application` and keep it around there. After it has been initialized, you can get and use it more or less anywhere you like.

Comment: TTS is initialized in the activity before. Making a good match for solution two. But how do you pass the TTS into this class?

Comment: Add a constructor to your `Location` class that takes a reference to the TTS engine as parameter. Assign that to a member variable and you'll be able to use it within that class. For example: `public Location(TextToSpeech tts) { talk = tts; }`.

Comment: Ahh, I was hesitant at first, but realized there was an error in another part of the code, preventing this got it working w/t suggestion 2, and your remark above. Thanks!!